# Can you join multiple Realms without paying?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

If you haven’t subscribed to Minecraft Realms, i.e. you haven’t bought anything, are you only limited to one Realm you can join or you can join/be invited to multiple Realms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join as many Realms as you want! You only need to pay if you want to OWN a Realm. This can be confirmed with a screenshot from the [How do I join a Realm](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1668614-joining-a-player-s-realm) FAQ:

[image]

Also, with a quick Google search I was able to find this picture that also confirms that is possible to join multiple Realms:

[image]

Comment: Do you have to buy something first though?

Comment: I have edited the answer, you don't need to pay if you want to join a Realm.